# 'Cannot implicitly convert type' when trying to get returned object from delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, .net-3.5

```
private Func<Order, OrderResult> GetDispatcherForOrder(Order order)
{
    switch (order.Type)
    {
        case "A":
            return dispatcher => DispatchA(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        case "B":
            return dispatcher => DispatchB(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("order.Type");
    }
}
```

DispatchA and DispatchB return a OrderResult object.
I'm calling it like this

```
Order x = GetOrder();
OrderResult myResult = GetDispatcherForOrder(x);
```

And i get this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<Order, OrderResult>' to 'OrderResult'
```

How can i get the OrderResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For when you must have a delegate (nothing in your code tells me that you do):

```
private Func<Order, OrderResult> GetDispatcherForOrder(Order order)
{
    switch (order.Type)
    {
        case "A":
            return dispatcher => DispatchA(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        case "B":
            return dispatcher => DispatchB(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("order.Type");
    }
}

Order x = GetOrder();
Func<Order, OrderResult> myFunction = GetDispatcherForOrder;
OrderResult myResult = myFunction(x);
```

For when you just need to get OrderResult:

```
private OrderResult GetDispatcherForOrder(Order order)
{
    switch (order.Type)
    {
        case "A":
            return DispatchA(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        case "B":
            return DispatchB(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("order.Type");
    }
}

Order x = GetOrder();
OrderResult myResult = GetDispatcherForOrder(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your're trying to assign a delegate to a `OrderResult` object. I think you may wanted to write:

```
Func<Order, OrderResult> myResult = GetDispatcherForOrder(x);
```

Comment: But how do I get the OrderResult object?

Comment: @HélderGonçalves use
    Func<Order, OrderResult> myResult = GetDispatcherForOrder;
    OrderResult resultObj = myResult(x);

Although, in this case you could use a normal method that just returns OrderResult.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Func<Order, OrderResult> GetDispatcherForOrder(Order order)
```

Is a method that returns a delegate. But based on your example usage:

```
Order x = GetOrder();
OrderResult myResult = GetDispatcherForOrder(x);
```

You probably want something like this:

```
private OrderResult GetDispatcherForOrder(Order order)
{
    switch (order.Type)
    {
        case "A":
            return DispatchA(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        case "B":
            return DispatchB(order.Id, order.Info, ...);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("order.Type");
    }
}
```